# How to install Gtk.glade module or libglade in python3

Tags: python, object, gtk, pygtk, glade

hi im study programming by Gtk3 and i  try to using glade i installed it,
But when i try to load the file from glade I have the problem:

```
" AttributeError: 'gi.repository.Gtk' object has no attribute 'glade' "
```

or this when I using only (Gtk.Builder):

```
 " AttributeError: 'Builder' object has no attribute 'glade' "
```

I know i should to install glade in python3 But I dont now how to install it after download it >>__<<
thank U pleas help me

---

```
   #!/usr/bin/python3.3
from gi.repository import Gtk
import pygtk
gu= Gtk.Builder()
gui = gu.glade.XML("1111.glade")


 "AttributeError: 'Builder' object has no attribute 'glade'
```

---

```
    #!/usr/bin/python3.3
from gi.repository import Gtk
import pygtk

gui = Gtk.glade.XML("1111.glade")



" AttributeError: 'gi.repository.Gtk' object has no attribute 'glade' "
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GTK objects don't have a `glade` property. Given a `Gtk.Builder` object `gu`, you should be calling something like `gu.add_from_file("1111.glade")`.

Also, don't import `pygtk` when working with GTK 3. PyGTK only supports GTK 2; GTK 3 is automatically handled by Python bindings for gobject-introspection, which you get when importing `gi.repository`.